# How do I reconfigure PHP (in ubuntu)?

Tags: php, ubuntu, lamp

I setup a LAMP environment on my Ubuntu 10.4 machine.

I used the tasksel install lamp-server to set it up.

I found out that it was not configured with "lCURL" (php libcurl module). Therefore I installed curl (apt-get install curl). Now I have to reconfigure PHP.

How do I reconfigure only php ?

Comment: Very true. I should've used it properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install the `php5-curl` package. Debian (and Ubuntu) package most PHP extensions as separately loadable modules. Don't forget to restart Apache afterwards using `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart` (No, an `apache2ctl graceful` will not do)

Comment: well spotted! curl will only install the curl command line tool.

Answer (score 1):

`dpkg-reconfigure php` or `dpkg-reconfigure php5` works on Debian Linux -- which is the base for Ubuntu as far as I know so give that a go.

Comment: nothing happened :) I guess it completed, but nothing happened.